# Can I use AES Encryption in Django + MySQL? If yes, will it affect the use of Django's ORM and other features?

Tags: python, mysql, django

We are migrating our PHP codebase to Django. In the current application, all database columns are encrypted (except ID) using AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT.
something like this:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO users SET 
        username = AES_ENCRYPT('".$email."','".$key."') , 
        email = AES_ENCRYPT('".$email."','".$key."') ";
```

```
$sql = "SELECT id , AES_DECRYPT(username ,'".$key."'), AES_DECRYPT(email,'".$key."')"
```

Can this code be replicated in Django and is it possible to still maintain the cool features of Django like migration and ORM?

Comment: Django will store and retrieve your data *as is*. When your data gets retrieved for instance, you will need a library which will then decipher your data.